# Посчитать сумму значений по разным полям объектов

Tags: java, массивы

Есть массив объектов `Car[] cars`. У объектов есть поля: `Weight, Price`.

Надо посчитать сумму значений всех `Weight` и всех `Price`.

Я сделал два метода, которые почти идентичны. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать один универсальный метод, в который можно было бы просто передать инфу о том, какое поле надо посчитать.

```
public static void sumOfWeights(Car[] cars) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (Car car : cars) {
        sum += car.getWeight();
    }
    System.out.println("\nTotal weight of all cars = " + sum + " ton");
}

public static void sumOfPrices(Car[] cars) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (Car car : cars) {
        sum += car.getPrice();
    }
    System.out.println("\nTotal price of all cars = " + sum);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Передавайте функцию, которая будет предоставлять нужные данные из объекта car в самой функции.

```
public static int sumBy(Car[] cars, Function<Car, Integer> selector) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (Car car : cars) {
        sum += selector.apply(car);
    }
    return sum;
}


...
int sumOfWeights = sumBy(cars, Car::getWeight);
int sumOfPrices = sumBy(cars, Car::getPrice);
System.out.println("\nTotal weight of all cars = " + sumOfWeights + " ton");
System.out.println("\nTotal price of all cars = " + sumOfPrices);
```

Но всё уже давно реализовано

```
int sumOfWeights = Arrays.stream(cars).mapToInt(Car::getWeight).reduce(0, Integer::sum);
int sumOfPrices = Arrays.stream(cars).mapToInt(Car::getPrice).reduce(0, Integer::sum);
```

Comment: Супер, спасибо! В первом варианте как раз то, о чем я думал, но не знал как сделать. Я пока только начал изучать java поэтому в моём задании второй вариант рановато применять, такие штуки на курсе не проходили ещё, но я обязательно внимательно разберусь)

Answer (score 1):

Как с этими вещами в Java сейчас- не знаю, но когда-то, давным давно (еще когда доллар был по 25 рублей), это можно было сделать так (через рефлексию):

```
public static void sumOf(Car[] cars, String methodName) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (Car car : cars) {
        method = car.class.getDeclaredMethod(methodName);
        sum += method.invoke(null)        
    }
    return sum;
}

Cars[] cars = new Cards[];
//...
sum1 = sumOf(cars, "getWeight");
sum2 = sumOf(cars, "getPrice");
```

Где-то оно и может пригодиться, но злоупотреблять не нужно

Comment: @IR42 у каждого car свой жеж метод

Comment: Спасибо, вроде бы хороший способ, но IDEA начинает предлагать добавить кучу каких-то исключений,  поэтому я пока другим воспользуюсь. Но эта штука с рефлексией интересная, запомню)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Car [] cars = new Car[3];
    cars [0] = new Car(1,3);
    cars [1] = new Car(2,4);
    cars [2] = new Car(3,5);

    System.out.println(sum(cars, Car::getPrice));
    System.out.println(sum(cars, Car::getWeight));
}

public static <K> Integer sum(K[] cars, Function<K, Integer> function) {        
    return Arrays.stream(cars)
            .map(function)
            .reduce(0, (a, b) -> a + b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Выносим в отдельный метод суммирование значений массива объектов по определенному полю:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Car[] cars = {new Car(10, 20), new Car(30, 40)};

    System.out.println(sumByField(cars, Car::getWeight)); // 40
    System.out.println(sumByField(cars, Car::getPrice));  // 60
}

public static int sumByField(Car[] cars, ToIntFunction<Car> mapper) {
    return Arrays.stream(cars).mapToInt(mapper).sum();
}
```

В классе `Car` должны присутствовать геттеры, для соответствующих полей:

```java
public class Car {
    int weight;
    int price;

    public Car(int weight, int price) {
        this.weight = weight;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getWeight() { return weight; }
    public int getPrice() { return price; }
}
```